# Where can i find jar files for graphhopper?

Tags: android, eclipse, graphhopper

I am new in working with Graphhopper. I want to integrate Graphhopper in my Android project but i cannot find any jar files which are to be included as library in my project. I use eclipse for my android development. Where can i find jar files for graphhopper.

Thanks,
Udit

Comment: https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/tree/0.3/android

Comment: https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/tree/master/android/libs

Comment: @Muhammad Babar The link that you have given is the sample demo apk, which i cannot use for the library.

Comment: @ravindra.kamble This list of libraries doesn't include any library for graphhopper. It only includes jar files for mapsforge.

Comment: Download from here http://mvnrepository.com/search.html?query=com.graphhopper

Comment: Thanks @ravindra.kamble for the last link. I could get the jars of the core. Can you please paste that as an answer so that i can mark it as accepted. Thanks

Comment: Why not use gradle or maven so that you don't need to include the libs in your project?

Comment: @Karussell You are correct. I am trying to work with Maven. Maven is new to me so maybe it would take sometime, but i will try and do that. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include graphhopper libraries using gradle.

Look at official android app in graphhopper' site.

https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/master/android/app/build.gradle

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer was posted above as comment  by ravindra.kamble
http://mvnrepository.com/search.html?query=com.graphhopper